# Swagger JWT definition is failing

Tags: .net-core, jwt, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am having problems in swagger when I configure it for .Net Core 6.

I am getting next error message:

> 'SwaggerUIOptions' does not contain a definition for 'AddSecurityDefinition' and the best overload of the extension method 'SwaggerGenOptionsExtensions.AddSecurityDefinition(SwaggerGenOptions, string, OpenApiSecurityScheme)' requires a receiver of type 'SwaggerGenOptions'

```
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My service");
        c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;

        c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            Scheme = "Bearer",
            BearerFormat = "JWT",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header
        });

    });
```

I am adding the second parameter as null and fails anyway.

What is wrong?

Comment: No love using Github Co-Pilot?

Answer (score 2):

AddSecurityDefinition is should be done in AddSwaggerGen

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
     c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header
    });
});
```